# What skills would a software developer need to get a job in space research or exploration organization?

Tags: space, software

I am in the field of software programming. What skills should I brush up and gear up to get a job in space exploration and the observatory industry? What are various job profiles in terms of software development in this field?

Comment: @san [This article from Cornell University's Astronomy Department](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/careers.php) should help you get started.

Comment: You may have better luck at [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming/What-skills-should-a-programmer-have-to-work-in-the-aerospace-or-medical-industry).

Comment: I have a perfect answer yet are forbidden by the (Stasi :) police to post. It depends whether you want an engineering or scientific job. For science you need to know physics first and use CS as tools. In both cases, machine learning and data visualisation are in most demand.

Comment: @Ska I love programming , so I want to be a software engineering .